# What is the meaning of the `allow_string` argument to `is_a`?

Tags: php, instanceof

PHP recently added a [third argument](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php#refsect1-function.is-a-changelog) to the `is_a` function. It's a boolean, and the documentation says,

> If this parameter set to FALSE, string class name as object is not allowed. This also prevents from calling autoloader if the class doesn't exist.

I don't get it. I get that you can prevent calling the autoloader unnecessarily, but it doesn't prevent you passing a string as a class name:

```
> class A {}
> $x = new A();
> echo is_a($x, 'A', false);
1
```

…in fact, you can't ever pass anything *but* a string:

```
> echo is_a($x, A, false);
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant B - assumed 'A' in php shell code on line 1
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() php shell code:0

Notice: Use of undefined constant B - assumed 'A' in php shell code on line 1

Call Stack:
   18.7644     625048   1. {main}() php shell code:0

1
```

That error message doesn't change when you change the third argument. What does *string class name as object* actually mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer has to do with subclassing. In PHP 5.3.7 `is_a` changed so that if the *first* argument was not an object, PHP would `__autoload` that argument, effectively attempting to make it an object:

```
> class A {}
> class B extends A {}
> echo is_a('B', 'A');
> // nada
> echo is_a('B', 'A', true);
1
```

Needless to say, that can lead to some unexpected side-effects and slowdowns, so adding the third argument gives you the choice about which behavior you want.

This all probably started when someone discovered that `is_a` and `subclass_of` [don't behave exactly like](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=42009) `instanceof`.